# Display two elements each taking 50% of screen height

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm trying to display two divs, one on top of the other, each taking half of the screen height

```
<ion-view view-title="Locator">
    <ion-content data-tap-disabled="true" scroll="false">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="contained">
          <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'></ui-gmap-google-map>
        </div>
        <div class="contained">
          <ion-scroll>
            <ion-list>
              <ion-item>Item 1</ion-item>
              <ion-item>Item 2</ion-item>
              <ion-item>Item 3</ion-item>
              <ion-item>Item 4</ion-item>
              ...
            </ion-list>
          </ion-scroll>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

First div should show a map the second a scrollable list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `vh` (viewport height) where the number will equal the percentage of the height.

So `50vh` will be 50% if the viewport height.

```css
div.contained {
  height: 50vh;
  /* DEMO STUFF BELOW */
  background: orange;
}
div.contained:first-child {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<ion-view view-title="Locator">
    <ion-content data-tap-disabled="true" scroll="false">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="contained">
          <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'></ui-gmap-google-map>
        </div>
        <div class="contained">
          <ion-scroll>
            <ion-list>
              <ion-item>Item 1</ion-item>
              <ion-item>Item 2</ion-item>
              <ion-item>Item 3</ion-item>
              <ion-item>Item 4</ion-item>
              ...
            </ion-list>
          </ion-scroll>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Haven't heard of 'vh' yet - Thank you.

Comment: No problem, other Viewport units you can use would be `vw, vh, vmin, vmax`

Comment: For anyone using Ionic 2+, I had to do the following to get the scrolling to work:  <ion-scroll scrollY="true">